# custom icon at end of directions route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a question about custom icon in google maps v3, i declare an icon

```
var size2 = new google.maps.Size(87,87);
var start_point2 = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
var foothold2 = new google.maps.Point(43,87);
var endIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://gidzior.net/map/conceptPark.png", size2, start_point2, foothold2);
```

i would like to use it in my map which is here http://gidzior.net/map/v3_animate_marker_directions.html, where in my code setup endLocation icon

CODE

```
var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;
  var markerArray = [];
  var position;
  var marker = null;
  var polyline = null;
  var poly2 = null;
  var speed = 0.0000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;
  var zoomed;
  var zoomedd;
  var zoomeddd;

  var step = 50; // 5; // metres

  var myPano;   
  var panoClient;
  var nextPanoId;
  var timerHandle = null;

  var size = new google.maps.Size(26,25);
  var start_point = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
  var foothold = new google.maps.Point(13,15);

  var car_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://gidzior.net/map/car.png", size, start_point, foothold);

  var size2 = new google.maps.Size(87,87);
  var start_point2 = new google.maps.Point(0,0);
  var foothold2 = new google.maps.Point(43,87);

  var endIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://gidzior.net/map/conceptPark.png", size2, start_point2, foothold2);

function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: car_icon,
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
    return marker;
}

function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    // Create a map and center it on Warszawa.
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    address = 'warszawa'
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    });

    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
    }
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
    stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
  }



    var steps = []

    function calcRoute(){

if (timerHandle) { clearTimeout(timerHandle); }
if (marker) { marker.setMap(null);}
polyline.setMap(null);
poly2.setMap(null);
directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
    });
    // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: map,
      suppressMarkers:true
    }
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
        var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: travelMode,
            waypoints: [{
                location:new google.maps.LatLng(52.185570, 20.997255),
                stopover:false}],
            optimizeWaypoints: false
        };

        // Route the directions and pass the response to a
        // function to create markers for each step.
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var route = response.routes[0];
        startLocation = new Object();
        endLocation = new Object();

        // For each route, display summary information.
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
          if (i == 0) { 
            startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
            startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
            //marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
            marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
          }
          endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
          endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
              polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
              bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);



            }
          }
        }

        polyline.setMap(map);
        document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = (polyline.Distance()/1000).toFixed(2)+" km";
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        //createMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red");
    map.setZoom(18);
    startAnimation();
    zoomed=false;
    zoomedd=false;
    zoomeddd=false;
    step = 50;
    }                                                    
 });
}




      var tick = 100; // milliseconds
      var eol;
      var k=0;
      var stepnum=0;
      var speed = "";
      var lastVertex = 1;




//=============== animation functions ======================
      function updatePoly(d) {
        // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
        if (poly2.getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline.getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

        if (polyline.GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
           if (poly2.getPath().getLength()>1) {
             poly2.getPath().removeAt(poly2.getPath().getLength()-1)
           }
           poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d));
        } else {
          poly2.getPath().insertAt(poly2.getPath().getLength(),endLocation.latlng);
        }
      }


      function animate(d) {
// alert("animate("+d+")");
        if (d>eol) {;
          map.panTo(endLocation.latlng);
          marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
          return;
        }
        if (d>eol-20000 && zoomeddd!=true) {
          map.setZoom(12); // or whatever value
          zoomeddd=true;
        }
        if (d>eol-10000 && zoomedd!=true) {
          map.setZoom(13); // or whatever value
          zoomedd=true;
        }
        if (d>eol-1500 && zoomed!=true) {
          map.setZoom(15); // or whatever value
          step = 15;
          zoomed=true;
        }
        var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
        map.panTo(p);
        marker.setPosition(p);
        updatePoly(d);
        timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
      }


function startAnimation() {
        eol=polyline.Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline.getPath().getAt(0));
        // map.addOverlay(new google.maps.Marker(polyline.getAt(0),G_START_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(new GMarker(polyline.getVertex(polyline.getVertexCount()-1),G_END_ICON));
        // map.addOverlay(marker);
        poly2 = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline.getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#0000FF", strokeWeight:0});
        // map.addOverlay(poly2);
        setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created your Icon (`endIcon`), and you know the place it should be (`endLocation`), so — once `endLocation` has been geocoded and found, create a marker there.

You already have a `createMarker` function. Make that generic so you can use it for different icons:

```
function createMarker(latlng, label, html, marker_icon) {
    // Note the new fourth argument
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        // this now uses the new argument
        icon: marker_icon,
        clickable: false,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
    return marker;
}
```

Change your existing code to pass in `car_icon` as the fourth parameter where the car is created.

Then just before this line

```
polyline.setMap(map);
```

`endLocation.latlng` will contain the coordinates of the end of the last leg of the journey. That should be your destination. So create a marker at that point.

`var destmarker = createMarker(endLocation.latlng,'Science Park','',endIcon);`

(Fill in `label` and `html` as required)

Comment: a did it a lite bit different, a created new function "createEndMarker" and write createEndMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red"); and it is ok, i know this is not optimal but sufficient

Comment: i have one question to you i'm trying to set the zIndex of the two icons because i want car icon to be higher, i write functions `function createMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
  icon: car_icon,
  clickable: false,
        zIndex: 1000
        });
    return marker;
}

function createEndMarker(latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
  icon: endIcon,
  clickable: false,
  zIndex: 500
        });
    return marker;
}` but it seems that zIndex not working

Comment: Best way to fix that is to move the site marker to the north just a fraction. The car marker will be stacked on top of any which are north of its location.

Comment: hmm, i did this - carIcon - zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5 and endIcon - zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<4, I think that's what you mean but I'm not sure:], thx again

Comment: No, I meant actually *move* the end-marker slightly to the north. It doesn't need to be much: 0.0001deg will be sufficient, and invisible on the map.

Comment: I am curious as why it was to help ?

Comment: Because if the car marker is slightly south of the site marker, it will be stacked on top. Markers get stacked with the south-most on top.